# Which is the physical device behind the logical /dev/___ device

Tags: linux, hardware, kernel

From time to time I get myself dealing with this same problem: from a linux logical block device (something below `/dev/`), I need to find the actual hardware behind it (something probably being listed on `lspci`).

The solution is always some side check for the specific hardware I am dealing with, using some contextual or historical data, or just by elimination, but when you are dealing with large heterogenous installations, that can be really hard to achieve. I would like to find a proper and more generic way to query the kernel about this. My guess is that must be some kind of link (and a way to query it) between the `major:minor` device numbers to the actual hardware.

Comment: Can you give a better example of what you're talking about? Disks? Storage?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is the function of `sysfs`, typically mounted at `/sys` although I am not sure where the path to every piece of hardware is kept for every device node.

Comment: Sure, in this case I have 3 possible block devices that can be on the machine: a HDD, a SSD or a fusion IO card. I can try writing specific checks for each one of them, but I would like to go in a more generic way (at least for block devices)

Comment: With a RAID controller or no?

Comment: Dont know exactly to be honest, but I am assuming that its not RAID

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Henriks answer is just what I needed. In the end is a generic way to map a (block) logical device to the actual underlying hardware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have udev configured in a good way you can look at places like /dev/disk/by-id/ and /dev/disk/by-path/ to see exactly what hardware matches /dev/sd?.

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed. You are awesome :)